# Chromosome representation in GA and DEAP

Tags: classification, genetic-algorithm, deap

I'm new to DEAP, and i want to represent my chromosome as a set of features which will be tested by SVM classifier, my problem now is how to represent my 35 features in the chromosome

Comment: @Gabriel IIharco In python

Answer (score 1):

Please find this link of Deap documentation.
You will find Example here:
https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/examples/index.html

also you will find here the representation methods of population.

https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorials/basic/part1.html

```
import random

from deap import base
from deap import creator
from deap import tools

creator.create("FitnessMax", base.Fitness, weights=(1.0,))
creator.create("Individual", list, fitness=creator.FitnessMax)
toolbox = base.Toolbox()

# Attribute generator
#                      define 'attr_bool' to be an attribute ('gene')
#                      which corresponds to integers sampled uniformly
#                      from the range [0,1] (i.e. 0 or 1 with equal
#                      probability)
toolbox.register("attr_bool", random.randint, 0, 1)

# Structure initializers
#                         define 'individual' to be an individual
#                         consisting of 100 'attr_bool' elements ('genes')
toolbox.register("individual", tools.initRepeat, creator.Individual,
toolbox.attr_bool, 100)

# define the population to be a list of individuals
toolbox.register("population", tools.initRepeat, list, toolbox.individual)
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)